# No Activity found to handle Intent act=android.provider.action.PICK_IMAGES

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activitynotfoundexception

I am making an Android app. I updated the target version from 28 to 33. I need to use the picture selector. I made it such that if the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is higher than S_V2, then action MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES is used. Otherwise Intent.ACTION_PICK used.
I extracted it into a tool. However, when I use it elsewhere in the project, sometimes it works, but sometimes I get an exception. The exception that I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.action.PICK_IMAGES cat=\[android.intent.category.DEFAULT\] dat=content://media/... typ=iamge/\* }
```

I don't understand why this exception is thrown.
My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2){
intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
} else {
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
}
intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

What should I do to solve the exception? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your error says you spelled `image` wrong - it says you spelled it `iamge`. Do you still get the same error when you spell the mime type correctly?

Comment: I checked code ,You are right ,I did make a spelling mistake in one place and missed it

Answer (score 0):

Put your code into a `try-catch` block like below,

```
 try {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2) {
           intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
       } else {
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
       }
       intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
       activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

If this not work try to use `Intent` code as a below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, class);
```

Comment: With the help of others, I understand the cause of this problem,It's my problem,,I have a spelling mistake in one place and missed it,Thanks for you help

Comment: good to know about that!!